# Order a list by the second and third text in a field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with a *text* column, `prono`, where values would contain four (4) combination numbers with `-` in-between them.

Example data:

```
id   prono
01   012-40-45-7894
02   045-12-13-8048
03   012-40-44-9704
```

I wanted to fetch the whole row and sort the list from my database **based on the second and third number**. Is there a way to do this?

Currently, and temporarily, I just sort them as a whole.

```
mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY prono");
```

And it would output like this (based from example data above):

```
id   prono
03   012-40-44-9704
01   012-40-45-7894
02   045-12-13-8048
```

But **what I need** for my output is like this (it would arrange based on the second and third pattern of numbers):

```
id   prono
02   045-12-13-8048
03   012-40-44-9704
01   012-40-45-7894
```

Is this doable? And how?

Comment: What are the numbers? Since you want to order the result by the middle numbers they must have some significance. Maybe you should put them in their own columns; that way you can more easily target them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use substring 
`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY substr(prono,5,2), substr(prono,8,2)`

Substring gives you the substring of prono from position 5 length 2 and the other stubstring from 8 length 2 (what is the substring you need to order. More information tu substr you can find on [Mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-functions.html)

Comment: Works like a charm. No explanation though?

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev It is quite self-explanatory.

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev Hope this is enough explanation?!